# Java generic - object instantiation

Tags: java, object, generics, instance

I want to check the object if it is of the required type and then use getters and setters on it. This is the code I've come up with so far, Is there any better way of doing it? I tried using Class<< T >> for the arguments but that does not give me the proper instance of the object.

```
public <T extends ClassA, P extends ClassB> T setSomething(T c, P ap) {     
            if (c instanceof ChildA1){
                if(ap instanceof ChildB1){  
                //getters and setters here
            c.setValue(ap.getIntValue());
             c.setId(ap.getId());
   }
   }
else if (c instanceof ChildA2){
            if(ap instanceof CHildB2){
//getters and setters here
       c.setValue(ap.getIntValue());
       c.setId(ap.getId());
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Im calling this method else where in the code like this:
a.setSomething(a, b);
 where b is of type ClassB, so Im not able to fetch the getter and setters of B's children.

Comment: I'm confused.  How do the types here relate, what object(s) do these getters and setters live on, and why do you want to instantiate what you're already passing through?

Comment: Can you share a fuller example illustrating what exactly you're trying to do? This code *should* work, but it goes against the OO principles, and I wonder if there's a better way to design this.

Comment: There are brackets missing.

Comment: Which getters and setters do you use in both cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I'm assuming the `//getters and setters here` code gets properties of the `ClassB` instance and sets properties of the `ClassA` instance (or vice versa).

If, for example, the objective is to get values from `ClassB` and set them in `ClassA`, you can achieve this with an `assign` method in the `ClassA` hierarchy :

```
public class ClassA {
    public void assign (ClassB b)
    {
        setSomeAProperty (b.getSomeBProperty());
        ... 
    }
}
```

Then you can override that method in sub-classes of `ClassA` :

```
public class ChildA1 extends ClassA {
    public void assign (ClassB b)
    {
        super.assign(b);
        if (b instanceof ChildB1) {
            ChildB1 b1 = (ChildB1) b;
            setSomeA1Property(b1.getSomeB1Property());
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then instead of `setSomething`, just call `a.assign(b)`.

Comment: Is there any better way of doing this? Im calling setSomething() method in a Controller class.